# Swift: Process UIImage data for use in Firebase custom TFLite model

Tags: ios, arrays, firebase, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am using Swift, Firebase, and Tensorflow to build an image recognition model. I have a re-trained MobileNet model that takes an input array of [1,224,224,3] copied into my Xcode bundle, and when I try to add data from an image as an input, I get the error: `Input 0 should have 602112 bytes, but found 627941 bytes.` I am using the following code:

```
    let input = ModelInputs()
    do {
        let newImage = image.resizeTo(size: CGSize(width: 224, height: 224))

        let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage)

        // Store input data in `data`

        // ...
        try input.addInput(data)
        // Repeat as necessary for each input index
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Failed to add input: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }



    interpreter.run(inputs: input, options: ioOptions) { outputs, error in
        guard error == nil, let outputs = outputs else {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)//ERROR BEING CALLED HERE
            return }
        // Process outputs
        print(outputs)
        // ...
    }
```

How can I re-process the image data to be 602112 bytes? I am so confused if someone could please help me it would be great :)

Comment: Are you using the Firebase ML Kit ?

Comment: @PannagSanketi yes I am. I can't find a guide anywhere for formatting input data to match MobileNet specifications in Swift. Only Obj-C

Comment: Hey @Ellek, the links are broken for some reason. Did you manage to get this working?

Answer (score 2):

Please check out the Quick Start iOS demo app in Swift on how to use a custom TFLite model:

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/tree/master/mlmodelinterpreter

In particular, I think this is what you are looking for:

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/mlmodelinterpreter/MLModelInterpreterExample/UIImage%2BTFLite.swift#L47

Good luck!

Comment: The first link has an extra %20.  Please use this link instead:  https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/tree/master/mlmodelinterpreter

Comment: Thank you so much! That is exactly what I need. You just saved me weeks of frustration lol